# Leap Years. Program in Ruby. Can someone explain?

Tags: ruby

Recently started with Ruby (no previous programming background).

Task: 
Write a program which will ask for a starting year and an ending year, and then puts all of the leap years between them (and including them, if they are also leap years). Leap years are years divisible by four (like 1984 and 2004). However, years divisible by 100 are not leap years (such as 1800 and 1900) unless they are divisible by 400 (like 1600 and 2000, which were in fact leap years)

code:

```
puts 'Input a starting year:'
start_year = gets.chomp
puts 'Input an ending year:'
end_year = gets.chomp
puts ''

while start_year.to_i <= end_year.to_i

    if start_year.to_f%400 == 0
        puts start_year
    elsif start_year.to_f%100 == 0
    elsif start_year.to_f%4 == 0
        puts start_year
    end
    start_year = start_year.to_i + 1
end
```

Can someone explain me this code step by step (literally)? and how console prints out those dates? where do we ask program in this code to print it?

Comment: Ruby has a pretty good [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core). Have you tried to look up the methods yourself?

Comment: Stacking on to what @Stefan said. I would look up loop methods and ruby operators to figure out how this code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through the code line-by-line. I'll both explain what's going on and show how it could be improved.

```
puts 'Input a starting year:'
start_year = gets.chomp
```

It will be more convenient to make `start_year` an integer so we don't have to keep converting between a string and an integer. We therefore should change the second line to

```
start_year = gets.to_i
```

If you examine the doc for [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) you will see that this is the same as

```
start_year = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Next,

```
puts 'Input an ending year:'
end_year = gets.to_i
puts ''

while start_year <= end_year
```

The last line requires that Ruby continue the `while` loop as long as `start_year <= end_year` is `true`. She exits the loop when this expression becomes `false` (when `start_year == end_year + 1`). Notice the simplification in the this line and in the lines below.

```
if start_year % 400 == 0
    puts start_year
```

If the year is divisible by `400` it is a leap year.

```
elsif start_year % 100 == 0
```

If the year is divisible by `100`, but not by `400`, it is not a leap year, so we do nothing, go to the end of the if/elsif/end clause and next execute `start_year += 1`.

```
elsif start_year % 4 == 0
  puts start_year
end
```

If the year is divisible by `4`, but not by `100`, is is a leap year. If `start_year % 4 != 0` it is not a leap year, so we do not print it.

```
start_year += 1
```

which Ruby expands to `start_year = start_year + 1`.

```
end
```

Return to the top of the loop and repeat.

**Better**

Here's a more Ruby-like way of writing that, converting the code to a method, using a single boolean expression and printing the return value of the method (an array of leap years).

```
def leap_years(start_year, end_year)
  (start_year..end_year).select { |yr|
    yr % 400 == 0 || (yr % 100 != 0 && yr % 4 == 0) }
end 

puts 'Input a starting year:'
start_year = gets.to_i
puts 'Input an ending year:'
end_year = gets.to_i

p leap_years(start_year, end_year)
  #=> [1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920]
```

`first_year..last_year` is a range (an instance of the class [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html)). `Range` includes the module `Enumerable` which provides it with the instance method [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

**Best**

The following would be easier way to obtain the leap years between two given years, by making use of the class method [Date::leap?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-leap-3F).

```
require 'date'

def leaps_between(first_year, last_year)
  (first_year..last_year).select { |y| Date.leap?(y) }
end

leaps_between(2000, 2016)
  #=> [2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016]

leaps_between(1900, 1916)
  #=> [1904, 1908, 1912, 1916]
```

Comment: `(first_year..last_year).select { |y| Date.leap?(y)}`

Comment: Thanks, @steenslag. I wasn't aware of [Date::leap?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-leap-3F) (or [Date#leap?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-leap-3F)). Readers, I previously had `(first_year..last_year).select { |y| Date.new(y,2,-1).day == 29 }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Print the sentence "Input a starting year:"
puts 'Input a starting year:'
# Create a variable start_year and set its content to the user's input stripping it from the new line character 
start_year = gets.chomp
# Read above
puts 'Input an ending year:'
end_year = gets.chomp
puts ''

# Do something while start_year is smaller or equal to end_year
while start_year.to_i <= end_year.to_i
    # If start_year divided by 400 doesn't have any remainder
    if start_year.to_f%400 == 0
        # Print that year in the console
        puts start_year
    # Else if ...
    elsif start_year.to_f%100 == 0
    elsif start_year.to_f%4 == 0
        puts start_year
    end
    # Increase start_year by 1
    start_year = start_year.to_i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask were the output comes from? `puts` prints to the console.

From the docs of [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts):

> Equivalent to
>
> ```
> $stdout.puts(obj, ...)
> ```

And from the docs of [`IO#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.
>
> ```
> $stdout.puts("this", "is", "a", "test")
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> this
> is
> a
> test
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would also use an iterator:

```
puts "Please select 2 years to calculate the leap ones in between.  What's your 1st one?"
start_year = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "...and your second one?"
end_year = gets.chomp.to_i

range = start_year..end_year

range.select do |year| 
  puts year if year % 4 == 0 or year % 400 == 0
end
```

The above while loop could also be rewritten as follows:

```
puts 'Input a starting year:'
start_year = gets.chomp.to_i
puts 'Input an ending year:'
end_year = gets.chomp.to_i
puts ''

while start_year <= end_year
  if start_year % 400 == 0 or start_year % 4 == 0
      puts start_year
  end
  start_year += 1
end
```